# Developer story should have option to move project

Tags: discussion, feature-request, developer-story

I was reading a few articles regarding how much time a recruiter take on reading your resume and the result is **3-4 secs**.

I normally applied for different domain jobs, but each time I have to share my same resume with position of project if I am applying it by **SO** or I need to upload resumes (different resume for different domain) from my computer.

So the main question is: If we have functionality to change the position of project like we had in previous developer story, will it be good?